# UIImage doesn't display in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, uiimage

I have an UIImageView in my UITableViewCell which is not being displayed. I get the image from the addressbook and save it as NSData but it seems that's not working.

I have a method getting the image:

```
if (ABPersonHasImageData(contactrec)){
        CFDataRef imageData = ABPersonCopyImageData(contactrec);
        [person setPic:(NSData *)imageData];
        CFRelease(imageData);
    }
```

My tableviewcell has the following method who's `cellPic` is linked to an UIImageView

```
-(void)setCellPic:(UIImage *) pic{
    cellPic.image = pic;
}
```

And finally, I have a contactsArray full of `person`s and for each row, I do:

```
Person *persona =[contactsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImage *contactImage = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)[persona pic]];
[cell setCellPic:contactImage];
```

When I debug the code, it seems like persona has for a contact whith pic 2000bytes but I think it's not doing well converting the NSData to UIImage. At least, when I debug the settle setCellPic, it says that cellPic.image is 0x0

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The problem was with the method setCellPic in the tableviewcell. As the UIImageView had the same cellPic name, the compiler thought I was calling the setter of the cellPic but cellPic wasn't a UIImage, it's UIImageView. So I've changed the method's name and it works fine now!
Thanks anyway!